# Run a function from python script from excel without running the whole script

Tags: python, excel, vba, python-2.7

I have developed a energy flow model for a microgrid in python. I have created a simple user interface in excel which runs the python script in background and displays the results in excel with some graphics. I do that by having a command buttom on my excel sheet. I use the following code in VBA to run the script.

> RunPython

The python program executes and stores the minute wise energy flow data in a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2vJy.png) (which contains the data for the whole year in min time resolution). The following function then take an input (output date) from the excel sheet and slices this data-frame to a particular date (which can be selected from excel) and data of that particular date is sent to excel (to plot the graphs).

```
def send_to_excel(output_date):
   workbook = xw.Book('Ahead_Model_new_plan.xlsm')
   raw_data_sheet = workbook.sheets['Raw_Data_Daily']
   results_sheet = workbook.sheets['Results']
   output_date = results_sheet.range('E12').value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
   df_excel_sliced = df_excel[df_excel['Date'] == output_date]
   raw_data_sheet.range('A1').value = df_excel_sliced
```

In total the program takes 40s to execute. What I want to do is, to create two buttons on my excel sheet. One which executes the whole program and saves the data in the data frame *df_excel* and once the whole program is executed, the other button will only execute the the function *def send_to_excel(output_date)* and send the data to the excel sheet. Then as I change the date from the excel sheet only *def send_to_excel(output_date)* is executed without executing the whole program and the data from the required date is sent to excel.

Right now when I change the date input from excel sheet and run the program for another date, the whole program runs and takes again 40s. I do not know how to run just that function without running the whole program.

I hope to my problem is clear. Please help me, I would be highly obliged.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the `send_to_excel(output_date)` function from the main python program. If the dataframe contains data for an entire year then there is no need to redownload every time the python script is run again. Just download the dataframe for each year (2018, 2019, 2020...) and store them somewhere excel or python can access them.

Turn the `send_to_excel(output_date)` into a stand alone python script that just pulls data from the data frame and then import it into excel. You will only need one button now and it will be much faster to pull the data. The user shouldn't have to download an entires year data everytime the function is called, the data should be stored locally or on a network where it can be easily accessed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought of this idea and also tried it. What I did was I saved the data of one year in an excel file and pulled it from another stand alone python script, made it in to an dataframe and then sliced it according to the date. But the problem is that the dataframe is huge. It has 525600 rows and 38 columns. It take around 30s to read the excel file, make a dataframe and then slice it and send it to the main excel sheet. Is there a smarter way? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Found a solution. I save the raw data as .pkl format (instead of csv) then load it again as a dataframe. I slice it to show the desired date. Takes 1s as a whole. Thanks a lot for your help.